# Linkedin Connect not using Linkedin website cookie?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I implemented a Linkedin connection in one of my apps. It works great but I need to enter my Linkedin credentials even if I'm already connected on Linkedin's website.

[image: Third party application auth]

Note my picture in the upper right corner.

When I authenticate on Linkedin's website, I have something like 10 minutes during which I don't need to authenticate, just accept my application's permissions requirements.

I would like to get this behavior as long as I'm connected to Linkedin's website. For instance, I would like that a user that comes on my application, if he's already logged on Linkedin, only needs to accept my permissions requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this is totally up to your server. if you reboot the service/app then yes you have to log in. but once a user is loggedin you can use the refresh token to keep him logged in as long is possible (unless he logs out himself).

if this does accure while the app isnt getting any restart. you should definitly look at the refresh token.

Comment: When I authenticate through my application, my token last for 60 days and I can refresh it. This is working as expected. But why do I need to authenticate through my application when I'm already logged in on LinkedIn ?

Comment: you do not. you get an authentication token. that you can use for the next 60 days.
so the key is just active. if you get prompted do authenticate then it is in your code.

Comment: I think I understood what I missed. When I disconect from my app, the token is invalidated only for my app. So when I try to reconnect, I'm still connected on the website but I have to authenticate again on my application in order to get a new token.